# Convert a Section of a C-String to a double

Tags: c++, arrays, file, double

I'm reading in a large data file into a `char[]` one line at a time. I need to sum several fields in the `char[]`.

Say I'm given an initialized: `char input[4270];` I want to find a number and here's what I know:

- It starts at index `1234`
- It will be no longer than 10 `char`s in length
- It will be of the format "567.89"
- If it is shorter than 10 `char`s the number will be left justified and space padded

After extracting the number at this index and another index I need to convert their sum back to a `char[]` so that I can write the output back to a file.

How do I accomplish this round trip?

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: How do I take a section of a char array and convert to a double and then back again?

Comment: @lefeal Convert text to double values? That can be done using the [`stod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function.

Comment: Your problem here is elementary programming skills, really. You seem unable to break a simple task into 3 even simpler subtask: locate number, locate end of number, pass the part in between to the right function. You figured out the first subtask but failed to put even that in C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert any legal `double` (independent of length) from a `char[]` by using [`stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/).

For example, say I'm given the input:

```
char cstring[] = "blah 13.42 blah blah";
```

If I know the index of the number I want to convert (here `5`) I can use that as follows:

```
const double num = stod(cstring + 5);
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/4oW1sH)]

Incidentally, if the index you provide points to white-space characters preceding the actual number `stod` will still work.

To go back to a `char[]` and you don't mind the result that would be printed from `printf`'s `%f` format, then I'd recommend simply using [`to_string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/) and copying. For example:

```
const string backToChars = to_string(num + 13.0);

copy(backToChars.cbegin(), backToChars.cend(), cstring + 5);
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/2kRzH7)]